# RegEx for eclipse search to finding occurrences with one line in method and missing another line

Tags: regex, eclipse

I have custom code for opening db connection and closing it. I need to find the methods where the close connection did not happen. I am looking for regEx which can give the places where this does not occur.

Update: The getConnection and closeconnection are defined in a single class and referred in multiple classes and multiple methods of same class. There are nesting of the multiple try-with-resources or regular try blocks(but without getconnection ) or other for/if blocks as well.

e.g.

```
public void method(){

 try{
     Connection conn= getConnection();

     }
 catch(){}
 finally{
  closeConnection();
 }
}
```

Comment: getConnection and closeConnection are not declared on every class, correct? Please add as much detail to your code snippet.

Comment: did my answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no nested `{...}` blocks, the regular expression to find the cases where `closeConnection` is missing is:

```
\btry\s*+\{[^\}]*\bgetConnection\b[^\}]*\}(?!\s*(catch\b[^\{]*\{[^\}]*\}\s*)?finally\b[^\{]*\{[^\}]*\bcloseConnection\b[^\}]*}\s*)
```

To look for `getConnection` not followed by `closeConnection` (not at all or not before the next `getConnection`, in case for files with multiple `getConnection`s) use the following:

```
\bgetConnection\b(?!((?!\bgetConnection\b)[\s\S])*\bcloseConnection\b)
```

Comment: There are nested try blocks and other if/for blocks, also there are many methods so the getConnection maybe in every method. It might be only once in a method. It will suffice if I am able to get the consecutive places where after getConnection there is no closeConnection.

Answer (score 0):

This will find occurrence of `getConnection()` without occurrence of `closeConnection()` in one file.

`"getConnection\(\);((?!closeConnection\(\);).)+$"gs`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Rygoq5/1

It assumes one file has only one connection. It will fail if one file has two function that both has `getConnection()` string.

Comment: This will not find places where `closeConnection` is missing that is followed by another one with a `closeConnection`.

Comment: @howlger Yes, that is why I assumed only one connection in one file. If I have to think about searching only in one function or one try catch block, it has a lot of case to think. What if You called `getConnection()` from one parent function and called `closeConnection()` from child function? You cannot expect all case. So I limited to simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the OP requested a Regex for Eclipse, this one will find try-catch blocks containg `getConnection` pattern but not `closeConnection`

```
(?m)try(.|\n)+getConnection(.|\n)+catch(.|\n)+(?<!\n\s+closeConnection[ ^}]+\n)[}]\n\s*\n
```

Matches

```
    try {
//      Connection conn = getConnection();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        
    } finally {

    }
}
```

Also matches

```
    try {
        //Connection conn = getConnection();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        
    }
}
```

Used with Search file utility as

[image]

If *"Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index "* error appears, try

```
(?m)try(.|\n)+getConnection(.|\n)+catch(.|\n)+(?<!\n\s{1,100}closeConnection[^ }]{1,1000}\n)[}]\n\s*\n
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am getting error- "Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 78."

Comment: Double checked and did not get that error, make sure the regex is complete and `Case Sensitive` and `Regular expression` are checked. Also, my eclipse version is `Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0)`, hope that is not an issue.

Comment: @jitendra added slightly different regex, replaced `+` with `{1,1000}`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I could not get new eclipse version as it is on the corporate. I have eclipse photon 4.8.0 2018 version. I am still getting the error on 85 column

Comment: Should work with that one too. Did you tried the updated regex? `(?m)try(.|\n)+getConnection(.|\n)+catch(.|\n)+(?<!\n\s+closeConnection[ ^}]{1,1000}\n)[}]\n\s*\n`

Comment: Still getting error: Look behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 84.

Comment: Try this one please `(?m)try(.|\n)+getConnection(.|\n)+catch(.|\n)+(?<!\n\s{1,100}closeConnection[ ^}]{1,1000}\n)[}]\n\s*\n`

Comment: I am getting error now: "Problems encountered during text search.
Problems encountered during text search.
Search pattern is too complex. Search canceled.
java.lang.StackOverflowError"
I think its my eclipse issue only. I did not receive previous error.